# What is the difference between "piedpilko" and "futbalo"?

Tags: word-usage

At first, I thought these words made a pair just like *malsanulejo-hospitalo*, where both words are used exactly the same, just having different origins. But, in some chat group I saw people commenting somebody's use of *piedpilko*. They said that that *spekti piedpilkon* means looking at the actual ball, and not following the game, which is usually the meaning intended. I'm thinking this pair is more like *televidilo-televido*, where one is the object and the other the phenomenon as a whole. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

- **Piedpilko** may have the same meaning as **piedpilkado**, which is a general name for association football, rugby, American football and other similar sports. ([Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piedpilkado)) ([NPEV](http://vortaro.net/#piedpilko))
- The main meaning of **piedpilko** is the actual ball used in these games. ([Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piedpilko)) ([ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/pilk.html#pilk.pied0o))
- **Futbalo** is association football (abbreviated as *soccer* in the US). ([Vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futbalo)) ([ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/futbal.html#futbal.0o)) ([NPEV](http://vortaro.net/#futbalo))

Comment: Yes, I think that the differences is between the football as american and the soccer (american) that in the rest of the world is called football